# Building apache ODE from the source Jruby and Buildr

Tags: jruby, buildr, apache-ode

I need to build apache ODE 1.3.5 from the source. Building from the source is important for me because we plan to make some changes in the `ODE` code. I tried out their [instructions](http://ode.apache.org/developerguide/building-ode.html) for building. I was able to install `jruby` 1.5.1 but I was not able to install `buildr` 1.4.4 using the said version of `jruby`. I googled a bit and it seemed like I had to upgrade to `jruby 1.6.2`. After the newer version of `jruby`(1.6.2), I was able to install `buildr 1.4.4` but when I go to the root of the `ODE` source and execute the following command

```
buildr package test=no
```

I get the below exceptions on the console

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- rubygems/source_info_cache
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:41
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:17
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/lib/buildr/core.rb:29
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/lib/buildr.rb:20
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/lib/buildr.rb:29
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-java/bin/buildr:18
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063
   (root) at c:\jruby-1.6.2\bin\buildr:19
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is my first interaction with `jruby` as well as `buildr`. I appreciate any pointers towards the building of this repository.

**Edit 1:** Below is the result of `jruby -S gem list` after installing `jruby 1.7.13` and `buildr 1.4.19`

```
C:\Users\16030053.CS-6606-DT>jruby -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

atoulme-Antwrap (0.7.5 java)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
builder (3.2.2)
buildr (1.4.19 java)
bundler (1.15.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
ffi (1.9.3 java)
hoe (3.7.1)
jruby-openssl (0.9.5 java, 0.8.10)
jruby-pageant (1.1.1 java)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.8.0 java)
json_pure (1.8.0)
krypt (0.0.2)
krypt-core (0.0.2 universal-java)
krypt-provider-jdk (0.0.2)
minitar (0.5.4)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
orderedhash (0.0.6)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.0.1)
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.5)
rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
xml-simple (1.1.2)

C:\Users\16030053.CS-6606-DT>
```

**Edit 2** When I execute the command `buildr package test=no --trace` in `apache-ode-sources-1.3.5`, I get the following errors

```
F:\apache-ode-sources-1.3.5>buildr package test=no --trace
Buildr aborted!
SyntaxError : F:/apache-ode-sources-1.3.5/tasks/jbi.rake:79: formal argument cannot be an instance variable
        Tempfile.open("MANIFEST.MF") { |@jbi_xml_tmp| @jbi_xml_tmp.write descriptor }
                                                   ^
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:497:in `load_tasks'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:494:in `load_tasks'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:224:in `load_buildfile'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:535:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:220:in `load_buildfile'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:130:in `run'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:535:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/buildr-1.4.19-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:128:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
c:\jruby-1.7.13\bin\buildr:23:in `(root)'

F:\apache-ode-sources-1.3.5>
```

Comment: Can you try with Jruby 1.7.13 and buildr 1.4.19
Can you execute this command and share it after installing the above versions
jruby -S gem list

Comment: @Sathwik updated the question with the output of the said command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the response of @sathwik on `apache-ode` mailing list that helped me compile the ode source for version `1.3.5`

> Hi Muhammad,
>
> Use jruby 1.7.13 and buildr 1.4.19
>
> Edit file `<ode 1.3.5 source>/tasks/jbi.rake`. Find and Replace the
>   initialize method with the content below
>
> ```
>   def initialize(*args)
>     super
>     prepare { path("lib").include((component.libs +
> bootstrap.libs).flatten.uniq) }
>
>     enhance do
>       case jbi_xml
>       when String
>         path("META-INF").include jbi_xml.path, :as=>"jbi.xml"
>       when nil, true
>         # Tempfiles gets deleted on garbage collection, so we're going to
> hold on to it
>         # through instance variable not closure variable.
>         @jbi_xml_tmp = Tempfile.new('MANIFEST.MF')
>         @jbi_xml_tmp.write descriptor
>         path("META-INF").include @jbi_xml_tmp.path, :as=>"jbi.xml"
>         @jbi_xml_tmp.close
>       when Proc, Method
>         @jbi_xml_tmp = Tempfile.new('MANIFEST.MF')
>         @jbi_xml_tmp.write jbi_xml.call.to_s
>         path("META-INF").include @jbi_xml_tmp.path, :as=>"jbi.xml"
>         @jbi_xml_tmp.close
>       end
>     end
>   end
> ```
>
> Besides the above changes I had to change line 37 of `dependencies.rb`
>   file from
>
> ```
> AXIS2_WAR           = "org.apache.axis2:axis2-webapp:war:1.3" to
>
> AXIS2_WAR           = "org.apache.axis2:axis2-webapp:war:1.6.2"
> ```
>
> The above change was needed because all the repositories containing
>   reference to `axis2-webapp:war:1.3` are down. Furthermore, you need to
>   add following line at the end of `repositories.rb` file
>
> ```
> repositories.remote << "http://people.apache.org/~vanto/m2/"
> ```
>
> This is required to fulfill one of the required dependencies namely
>   `xdoclet:xjavadoc-1.1-j5`.